# How can I remount with only a few mount options explicitly specified, while leaving other options unaffected?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, mount

I want to remount `/dev/sr0` (`/media/cdrom0`) with the `exec` option, while leaving **all** other options as-is.

In the below example, it's clear that `sudo mount -o remount,exec` attempts to change the `ro` option to `rw`, although I only explicitly specify `exec`.

How can I remount a device without changing options not specified explicitly?

```
$ mount | grep cdrom
/dev/sr0 on /media/cdrom0 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,user)
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/cdrom0
mount: /media/cdrom0: cannot remount /dev/sr0 read-write, is write-protected.
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec,ro /media/cdrom0
$
```

*Is the solution merely to copy paste the list of options output by `mount | grep cdrom` and provide them in `-o remount ...`*?

Answer (score 2):

Run `man mount` and type: `/^ +remount$` and hit enter to find the relevant section of the man page, the third paragraph of which says:

> The  remount  functionality  follows the standard way the mount command works with options from fstab.  This means that mount does not read fstab (or mtab) only when both device and dir are specified.

In other words, if you don't specify both the device and the mount-point, `mount -o remount` **will** read `/etc/fstab` and use the other options found there for that device/mount-point.

i.e. try:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0
```

or just use add `,ro` as you already did.  It's less typing.

Comment: Thanks. I haven’t configured fstab, so will `mount` read mtab in that case and use the mount options there as defaults for `-o remount`, only replacing the options explicitly specified?

Comment: When both device and mount point are specified, which options are used by default in that case? The `mount` default set of options? If so, shouldn’t your command fail, since `rw` is part of the default set AFAIK?